# Google Tag Manager Not Sending Ecommerce Data to Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I added the code below via GTM, when I make a test purchase I see the data layer but the ecommerce data is not being sent to analytics. I have the tag firing on a page view of the success page.

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

var productArray = [];
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ved");
   var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("qty-class");
   var sku = document.getElementsByClassName("productid");
   var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price-class");

        var y = x[0].innerHTML;
        var len=x.length;
    for(i=0; i < len; i++){
      var pO = {};
      pO.name = x[i].innerHTML;
      pO.quantity = parseInt(quantity[i].innerHTML);
      pO.price = parseInt(price[i].innerText);
      pO.sku = sku[i].innerHTML;
      pO.category = 'MyCategory';

      productArray.push(pO);
    };

   var revenue = document.getElementById("order-total").innerText;
   var ship = document.getElementById("shipping").innerText;
   var tid = document.getElementById("t_id").innerText;

dataLayer.push({
'transactionId': tid,
'transactionAffiliation': 'MyWebsite',
'referrer':{{ref}},
'transactionTotal': parseInt(revenue),
'transactionTax': 0,
'transactionShipping':parseInt(ship),
'transactionProducts': productArray,
'event':'transactioncomplete'
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are implementing standard ecommerce tracking (as opposed to enhanced ecommerce). To track the transaction into GA, you need to use a "Transaction" type tag, and not a pageview tag. It should be pretty clear [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en) (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en) on how to set that up in GTM. Your event `transactioncomplete` would then trigger this tag.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have enabled enhanced ecommerce in the admin section of GA.  Second, it looks like you are missing the ecommerce portion in the dataLayer.  See the [GTM docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases)

Comment: Just a small comment, it doesn't look like OP is using EE, but rather just standard ecomm.